# Why is nginx gziping tar.gz archives?

Tags: nginx, gzip

I have the following `gzip` configuration at the `nginx.conf` file:

```
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

and the problem is that it is compressing `tar.gz` archives but I don't understand why since their mime-type is `application/x-gzip`.

How could I possible fix this without fulling remove the `gzip`? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you believe that nginx is compressing the file?

Comment: @MichaelHampton because when I download it I have to extract it 3 times instead of two. (`7z x foo.tar.gz`, `7z x foo.tar`, `7z x foo`)

Comment: And what's in the file? Isn't that how it was originally packed?

Comment: @MichaelHampton just text and python files. The tar.gz packages are created using normal GNU/Linux tools, and when I remove those lines from the `nginx.conf` file, I can correctly download the `tar.gz` packages and decompress them!